# Copy DataTable Column's values into another DataTable row C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, datatable

I have two data tables Both Data table are consist on seven columns. I want to copy column values of first data table into second data table row. Source table's rows cannot be greater than 7 rows

for Example

```
Source          Destination 
SourceColumn    ColumnOne   ColumnTwo    ColumnThree    ColumnFour ......
   1              1           2            3                4
   2
   3
   4 
   6
   7
```

I have found this function but this not works as expected

```
   private void CopyColumns(DataTable Source, DataTable Destination, params string[] Columns )
    {
        foreach(DataRow SourceRow in dtable.Rows)
        {
            DataRow DestinationRow = dt.NewRow();
            foreach(string ColumnName in Columns)
            {
                DestinationRow[ColumnName] = SourceRow[ColumnName];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(DestinationRow);
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to shift each value to appropriate column in destination table?

Comment: What if the first table contains more than 7 row? Or that won't be the condition at all? Basically you want to convert rows to the columns ?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention source table's rows cannot be more than 7 rows

Comment: Looks like you actually need only __one__ loop ?-)

Comment: Yes, I need loop for shift column of source table values into row of destination table @TaW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the sample code. Here `dt1` and `dt2` are source and destination tables respectively.

Assume that  `dt1` is having same number of rows as the number of columns in `dt2`.

```
var newRow = dt2.NewRow();  //dt2 is the destination table. Creating new row for destination table.

for (var i = 0;i < dt2.Columns.Count;i++)
{
    var row1 = dt1.Rows[i];
    newRow[i] = row1[0];
}

dt2.Rows.Add(newRow); //Adding new row to the destination table.

var xRow = dt2.Rows[0]; //Retrieving row for displaying the data to Console.

for (var j = 0; j < dt2.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xRow[j]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made some changes in your code snippet and it works as expected